# how to use a non-european language with a python library

Tags: python, pygame, arabic

I'm relatively new to programming and recently I've started playing around with pygame (set of modules to write games in python).  I'm looking to create a program/game in which some of the labels, strings, buttons, etc are in Arabic.  I'm guessing that pygame has to support Arabic letters and it probably doesn't?  Or could I possibly use another GUI library that does support Arabic and use that in unison with pygame?  Any direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: One obstacle you may face is that pygame does not (currently) support rendering of right-to-left languages such as Arabic: http://pygame.motherhamster.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61. The link may be helpful anyway since it shows a workaround and some example code.

Answer (score 5):

Well Python itself uses Unicode for everything so that's not the problem. A quick googling also shows that PyGame should be able to render Unicode fonts just fine. So I assume the problem is more that it can't find fonts for the specific language to use for rendering.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668359/unicode-fonts-in-pygame) is a short example for PyGame and especially [this](http://www.unifont.org/fontguide/) link should be useful.

[This](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) is the important library - so specifying a font that can render your language and using it to render it should work fine. Probably a good idea to write a small wrapper

Nb: Haven't used PyGame myself so this is based on speculation and some quick search about how PyGame renders fonts.

PS: If you want the game to work reliably for all of your users, it's probably a good idea to include an Open Source font in your release, otherwise you need some methodology to check if the user has some fonts installed that will work fine - a probably non-trivial problem if you want Xplattform support.

Answer (score 0):

Python [does support unicode-coded source](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Set the coding of your source file to the right type with a line of the form `# coding: [yourCoding]` at the very beginning of your file. I think `# coding: utf-8` works for Arabic.

Then prepend your string literals with a `u`, like so:

```
u'アク'
```

(Sorry if you don't have a Japanese font installed, it's the only one I had handy!)

This makes python treat them as unicode characters. There's further information specific to Arabic on [this site](http://www.spencegreen.com/2008/12/19/python-arabic-unicode/).

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers are great.
There is also a great built-in python function called unicode. It's very easy to use.
I wanted to write Hebrew text so I wrote a function:

```
def hebrew(text):
    # Encoding that supports hebrew + punctuation marks
    return unicode(text,  "Windows-1255")
```

Then you can call it using:

```
hebrew("<Hebrew text>")
```

And it will return your text Hebrew encoded.

Comment: Uh, how does that help exactly? Changing the encoding from Unicode to Windows-1255 reduces the number of languages you can use...

Comment: Yeah I'd assume that if he's writing a PyGame for an Arabic audience he's already using some arabic strings in the source files, which means he's already using UTF-8 or something as the base encoding (another good thing about python3)