# Rendering unicode in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to render some unicode characeters on screen.

Using `pygame.font` displays a weird character.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")
FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 64)
font_surf = FONT.render("♛", True, pygame.Color("red"))
screen.blit(font_surf, (20, 20))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.delay(1000)
```

I also tried using pygame.freetype. It displays nothing at all.

```
import pygame.freetype
pygame.freetype.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")
FONT = pygame.freetype.Font(None)
FONT.render_to(screen, (20, 20), "♛", size=(40, 40))
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.time.delay(1000)
```

Comment: If it is a system font use SysFont(name, size, bold=False, italic=False)link to more info [SysFont](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont).. I some times put the .ttf font file in the game folder

Comment: unistr = u"♛"      [unicode string in pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668359/unicode-fonts-in-pygame)

Comment: Not including the font file could be the reason of your problem as it says @john taylor. You can see here a similar solution  [Unicode fonts in PyGame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668359/unicode-fonts-in-pygame)

Comment: FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("name_of_user_font.ttf",64)  and again remember the other users might not have the font needed so you may need to put it in your game folder also so it works on other computers

Comment: @johntaylor AFAIK this doesn't change anaything in Python 3.X. Am I wrong?

Comment: in 3.4 the only difference is  unistr = "♛"  there is no unistr = u"♛" like 2.7

Comment: @johntaylor `u'♛'` is a valid string literal in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.

Comment: good point @BlackJack, if you have it still runs a valid string literal on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: working 3.4 unicode]

You need to add your font name and location .

```
f = pygame.font.Font("segoe-ui-symbol.ttf",64)
```

On Python 3.4 you no longer need the `u` before `"♛"` like in Python 2.7.

```
 unistr = "♛"
```

sample based on that other link but for 3.4 as example is 2.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame
import sys


unistr = "♛"
pygame.font.init()
srf = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
f = pygame.font.Font("segoe-ui-symbol.ttf",64)
srf.blit(f.render(unistr,True,(255,0,0)),(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    srf.blit(f.render(unistr,True,(255,255,255)),(0,0))
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: `blit` complains that it cannot render Unicode above 0xFFFF, which contains Chinese characters that I need.  Your example is within 0xFFFF.