# Rendering unicode font with pygame

Tags: python, unicode, pygame

I'm currently attempting to render text read from a file onto the screen using pygame. However, when I attempt to render a non-standard Unicode character (i.e. Japanese hirigana), it responds only with an assortment of random characters and boxes. I've searched through everything I could find and nothing works. Any ideas? The file is properly encoded and read in UTF-8, so the problem is during the rendering stage.

My text rendering code:

```
def text(screen, pos, text='', font=None, color=BLACK, halign='LEFT', valign='TOP'):
    if font == None: font = pygame.font.Font(None,16)
    draw = font.render(text.encode('utf8'), True, color)
    pos = list(pos)

    if halign.upper() == 'CENTER': pos[0] -= font.size(text)[0]/2
    if halign.upper() == 'RIGHT': pos[0] -= font.size(text)[0]

    if valign.upper() == 'CENTER': pos[1] -= font.size(text)[1]/2
    if valign.upper() == 'BOTTOM': pos[1] -= font.size(text)[1]

    screen.blit(draw, pos)
```

The text I'm trying to render:

```
おはようございます、みんな！
```

The result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/88hBp.jpg

EDIT: After some testing, it turns out that it was the font I was using... Along those lines, does anyone know of an alternative to Segoe UI Light that has kana support?

Comment: I guess the text should not be encoded. `encode()` creates binary data suitable for storing not for rendering.

Comment: I have the same problem, with or without the 'encode()'... I have no idea what's going on (although removing it does change the result to [this](http://imgur.com/1YKCU4B))

Comment: Now at leeast the number of characters fits. It looks like the font does not support Unicode or that Unicode block.

Comment: Again, already checked. The font does indeed support the exact characters... I'm stumped.

Comment: `draw = font.render('おはようございます、みんな！', True, color)` *no* ˙encode()˙ as @KlausD. said already. From `font.render` reference: _Both Unicode and char (byte) strings are accepted_

Comment: And as I said already, I removed the 'encode()' and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Does it work if you put the text that's to be rendered directly into the code instead of reading it from a file? Even if your font should support it, have you tried it with a different font, such as Cyberbit? An executable MWE might help isolate the problem. Have you been able to run another example such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668359/unicode-fonts-in-pygame/668596#668596 successfully on your machine?

Comment: Turns out it was the font, despite it saying that it supported it... Now looking for a Segoe UI Light alternative with kana support.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, it's available setofont (`fonts-seto`)

```
    font_file = pygame.font.match_font("setofont")  # Select and 
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_file, 30)          # open the font
    writing = font.render(u"おはようございます、みんな！", True, (0, 0, 0))
```

[image: screenshot]