# How to display txt file to a pygame screen?

Tags: python-3.x, text, pygame, pong

I was wondering if it is possible to display text from a txt file onto a pygame screen. I am working on a game, and I am attempting to display the instructions from a text file in my game.

Here is what I did below:

```
def instructions():
    instructText = instructionsFont.render(gameInstructions.txt, True, WHITE)
    screen.blit(instructText, ((400 - (instructText.get_width()/2)),(300 - (instructText.get_height()/2))))
```

However I get the error:

```
line 356, in instructions
    instructText = instructionsFont.render(pongInstructions.txt, True, WHITE)
NameError: name 'pongInstructions' is not defined
```

My attempt however, is all trial and error because I am actually unsure of how to do this... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`gameinstructions` is not defined since python thinks it is a variable.

To tell python it is a string you need to put it in quotes:

```
instructText = instructionsFont.render("gameInstructions.txt", True, WHITE)
```

However that is probably not what you want. What you want to do is read the file. For that you should use the `with` statement to safely open and close the file:

```
with open("gameInstructions.txt") as f:
    instructText = instructionsFont.render(f.read(), True, WHITE)
```

I can not currently try the code out, but you might need to loop through the lines instead, if pygame can not handle several lines of text at once:

```
with open("gameInstructions.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        instructText = instructionsFont.render(line, True, WHITE)
```

Comment: I tried this code, however I get an error saying: line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 397: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: what version of python are you on? It seems to expect ascii, which the "â" character is not part of. From other posts I can see that it should support unicode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668359/unicode-fonts-in-pygame#668596

Comment: I'm running this in python 3.6.0

Comment: This is often caused by a wrong locale. Try forcing the encoding of your file with `open(filename, encoding='utf-8')` or checking if your locale is set properly

Comment: another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte#21190382

Comment: Thank you for helping out so much, however after forcing the encoding- nothing happens at all. My program freezes. At his point my code is `def instructions():
    screen.fill(TEAL)
    with open("pongInstructions.txt", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            instructText = instructionsFont.render(line, True, WHITE)
            screen.blit(instructText, ((400 - (instructText.get_width()/2)),(300 - (instructText.get_height()/2))))
            pygame.display.update()` Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know, I am not very familiar with pygame. Since you solved the original issue (instructions not defined), I recommend you move on and start a new question.

Comment: Alright, thank you so so much for all of your help and time!